# newsletter.send.php in django

Tags: python, html, django

As I'm just finishing my last part of programming of my website based on Django (& Python) I've been facing with a constant error in all applications which i have "Form.py" or "post", as you can see it in the below section:

**Not Found: /contact/email/newsletter.send.php
[28/Jan/2020 13:15:25] "POST /contact/email/newsletter.send.php HTTP/1.1" 404 3054**

I also have "Bootstrap" codes that works pretty good and I suppose this error is not occurring from the Django's programming part.

This error is almost occurring at 'SEND MAIL, ADD TO CART, ADD TO WISHING LIST, SIGN IN' parts; Which means all parts that concerned with Sending-Receiving and have "Form.py", have "newsletter.send.php" error and don't work, which I almost have NO PHP Codes at all in my website programming.
I also attached part of "Add to Cart" Html code below which i suppose is correct;
cart.py:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from shop.models import Product


class Cart(object):

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        product_id = (str(product.id))
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                     'price': str(product.price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
            self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        product_id = (str(product.id))
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.session.modified = True
```

context_processors.py:

```
from .cart import Cart


def cart(request):
    return{'cart': Cart(request)}
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 21)]


class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES,
                                      coerce=int)
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False,
                                initial=False,
                                widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'cart'
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    re_path(r'^add/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    re_path(r'^remove/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$',
            views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from shop.models import Product
from .cart import Cart
from .forms import CartAddProductForm


@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 update_quantity=cd['update'],)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'],
                                                                   'update': True})
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

html code for add to cart:

```
<form action="{% url "cart:cart_add" product.id %}" method="post">
     {{ cart_product_form }}
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input style="color:gray;" type="submit" value="add to cart">
</form>
```

I wonder if you could help me there!
Thank ya all!

Comment: What does "almost no php codes" mean? You should include the full stack trace.

Comment: you mean I should include PHP codes to my website programming?!

Comment: its not possible to build a website on Django + HTML?!

Comment: I don't know what you mean, in your question you say *almost* no php, implying you include some somewhere. You don't mention `newsletter.send.php` anywhere in the code you're showing here.